# How can we get DynamicData working with EFPocoAdapter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data, poco

My team is hoping to use the EFPocoAdapter, but are also hoping to use the DynamicData tools with it but are having some issues.

We basically added a "Dynamic Data Entities Web Application" project to the EFPocoAdapter Northwind sample solution (I am using the latest version, 1.03), referenced the needed assemblies and then uncommented and edited the line in the Global.asax.cs file that registers a context with the MetaModel to look like this:

```
model.RegisterContext(typeof(NorthwindEF.NorthwindEntities), 
      new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

We get this error: "The context type 'NorthwindEF.NorthwindEntities' is not supported."

The question we have is, how can we make this a valid context or how else can we hack things to make this work for us?

Any pointers are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: jason, are you guys still using the pocoadapter ? how did it work out for you

Comment: Hi ashish; no, we ended up ditching the it early on, shortly after this question was written. We were working against Oracle and the Oracle provider wasn't that great at giving us everything we needed and we decided against further-complicating our application's architecture and implementation with yet another layer. 

I think the idea of the EFPocoAdapter is great and would try to use it again if I were in charge of designing everything and had to use EF. Otherwise, I would probably stick with HNibernate until EF 2.0 is released and proves it is worth your time...but that's just my opinion!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the DynamicData.EFCodeFirstProvider, available from Nuget, just search for EFCodeFirstProvider. Then you use:

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(
            new EFCodeFirstDataModelProvider(() => new NorthwindEF.NorthwindEntities()),
            new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```