# Error in using Dynamic Data Entities Web Site in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-dynamic-data

I decided to use Dynamic Data Entities Web Site in VS2012.

So, I created this Web Site, then added `App_Code` directory and added a new `edmx` to it and named it `myDB.edmx`. After that I uncommented the code line in `Global.asax` which registers the entity context :

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(myDBEntities), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

But when I run the website this error occurs :

```
The context type 'myDBEntities' is not supported.
```

how can I fix it?

p.s: You now there are some differences between using L2S by `Dynamic Data L2S Web Site` and using Entity Framework by `Dynamic Data Entities Web Site`.

Comment: You need to add a little more information to your question. For example what kind of context, are you using code first, dbcontext or model first?
I had  a similar problem, and this question suggests you may be using the wrong constructor overload, or (depending on whether you're using code first) may need additional components:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440943/how-can-we-get-dynamicdata-working-with-efpocoadapter and [link]http://forums.asp.net/t/1451758.aspx/1
Try the suggestion at the end and see if that doesn't at least bring you closer to a solution

Comment: thanks buddy, 
As you see, at first I created my database and then created the edmx file from my database. everything is so clear, there are no complexity  and I don`t know why it dose not work...!

Answer (score 5):

I am still looking for the reason, but right now the only option is to create the project in VS2010 and then migrate the project into VS2012 and then I don't have any problem running the application

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens because in Visual Studio 2012 you get `DbContext` (instead of `ObjectContext` as in Visual Studio 2010) code generated by default for all new models created with the EF Designer. In order to solve one you need to revert back to `ObjectContext` code generation.

For more information see [Reverting to ObjectContext in EF Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the TT files from the model
2. Change the "Code Generation Stategy" to "Default"

Answer (score 0):

Within the Global.asax file, uncomment the other RegisterContext line instead.

```
 DefaultModel.RegisterContext( _
           New System.Func(Of Object)(Function() DirectCast(New [Your edmx](), IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext), _
           New ContextConfiguration() With {.ScaffoldAllTables = True} _
         )
```